# SQL get Max Date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, greatest-n-per-group

I need to have the last price for each product for each client . I am not really good with SQL  and I don't understand how I can do it.

Data :

[image]

What I want :

[image]

It is possible to have this data with a SQL request ?

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window function `ROW_NUMBER()`, if available in your RDBMS:

```
SELECT product, price, date, client
FROM (
    SELECT
        t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product, client ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM mytable t
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

In MySQL < 8.0:

```
SELECT product, price, date, client
FROM mytable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE t1.client = t.client AND t1.product = t.product AND t1.date > t.date
)
```

Comment: Thx that help me a lot.

Comment: Welcome @Sam! Glad that it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be a correlated subquery

```
SELECT product, price, date, client
FROM tablename a where date =
    (select max(date) from tablename b where a.product=b.product)
```

Comment: I would upvote, but I don't know if `in` optimizes as well as `=` in this situation.  I'm concerned that the optimization paths might sometimes be different.  With `=` and the right index, this should be the most performant solution.